# m.request with deserialization property is not returning a string

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

As per the example in [API documentation](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/mithril.request.html#using-different-data-transfer-formats), I am trying to use the m.request utility (with the deserialization flag set) to grab the contents of a .txt file as a string;

```
var file = m.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'file.txt', //
    deserialize: function(value) {
        return value;
    }
})
```

However, the output of

```
console.log(file);
```

is actually the string:

```
// function (){return arguments.length&&(a=arguments[0]),a}
```

not the expected content in the file. I am certain that I am missing something, or setting the m.request options incorrectly - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example it doesn't look like you're utilizing the deserializer right, but that's not your issue. But just FYI (per the docs) the deserializer:

**"By default, m.request uses JSON to send and receive data to web services. You can override this by providing serialize and deserialize options..."**

Your issue however is that the request function is asynchronous and thus returns a promise rather than the explicit values. You will need to receive the promise and execute on the value:

```
var file = m.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'file.txt', //
        deserialize: function(value) {
    return value;
    }
});

file.then(function(val) { console.log(val); });
```

The deserialize will still be called, and you can access the value. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Yep, I missed that. Thanks. BTW I am aware that I would probably want to parse the file inside the deserialize anonymous function, or just pass a reference to some utility function as opposed to parsing the file afterwards (ie. inside the .then()) - I assume that this is what you were referring to in regards to improper utilisation of the deserializer?